# Spring data JPA have selection of one table 1 get the details of table 2 as well

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables `Student` and `Student_Type`, Each student have each type, while selecting student table how to get the details Student_Type in Spring data JPA.

Student Enity

```
@Enity
@Table(schema="DATA", name="STUDENT")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(name="fname")
 private string fanme;

 @Column(name="lname")
 private string lanme;
 
 @Transiant
 private string config_type; // Studen_Type type should be populate on here  
}
```

Student_Type Enity

```
@Enity
@Table(schema="DATA", name="STUDENT_TYPE")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentType {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(name="type")
 private string type;

 @Column(name="stud_id") // Student `id` is referenced
 private string stud_id;

 @OneToOne(optional=false)
 @JoinCoulumn(name="stud_id" referencedColumnName= "id" insertable=false, updateble=false)
 private Student student;
}
```

While doing select query of `student` table how to get the `type` from `Student_type` table.

Sample data of `Student` table
| Id | fname | lname|
| --- | ----- |----|
| 1    | Raju  |     Mikel     |
| 2   |   Thomas |   George      |
| 3   |   Arun |   Nair      |

Sample data of `Student_Type` table
| Id | type | stud_id|
| --- | ----- |----|
| 1    | Performer  |     1     |
| 2   |   Avg |   2      |
| 3   |   Performer |   3      |

I'm new in Spring data JPA,

I tried the One to One mapping but its not working,
This is my native query,

StudentRepository

```
 @Query("select s.fname, s.lanme, st.type as config_type from student s left join student_type st on s.id=st.stud_id", nativeQuery=true)
List<Student> findStudetType();
```

Please help that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Student`, add:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="student")
private StudentType tudentType;
```

Secondly, change your query to JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Student s LEFT JOIN FETCH StudentType st")
```

FYI: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Comment: mappedBy="student" this `student` is the table name ?

Comment: It is working as expected, but it is taking more time to execute. Do we have another solution

Comment: "mappedBy="student" this student is the table name": this is this field name (private Student student)
"It is working as expected, but it is taking more time to execute. Do we have another solution": you may need to create another question and provide some info